# Need Help to display images from model

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-templates

I have a model named 'Page' and i want to store many images for each Page object.
So i created a Separate Model named 'Image' as a F.K of 'Page' model.

In my template,, i am displaying all the Page object as a list (using bootstrap), but for each object, i also want to show many images saved for each object, i cant figure out the loop part. I have given relavent Code below :

Models.py

```html
class Page(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField( )
    #description field
    des=models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=False)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # Uncomment if you don't want the slug to change every time the name changes
            #if self.id is None:
                    #self.slug = slugify(self.name)
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
            super(Page, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

def desti (instance,filename):
    return "%s/%s/%s"%(instance.page,instance.user,filename)

class image(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    page=models.ForeignKey(Page)
    images=models.ImageField(upload_to=desti, null=False ,blank=False)
```

Index.html

```html
{% for obj in page_list %}
        <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">)
            {% for obj2 in obj.images %}
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ }}" alt="IMAGE GOES HERE">
           <!-- want to display the images here as horizontal -->
          {% endfor %}
            <h1>this page has {{ obj.images }} images </h1>
                  <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">{{ obj.name }}</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ obj.des }}</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">ViewDetails</a>
                  </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably as simple as this:

```
class image(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    page=models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name='images')
    pic =models.ImageField(upload_to=desti, null=False ,blank=False)
```

In template:

```
{% for page in page_list %}
        <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">)
        {% for image_obj in page.images.all %}
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ image_obj.pic.url}}" alt="IMAGE GOES HERE">
       <!-- want to display the images here as horizontal -->
      {% endfor %}
<h1>this page has {{ page.images }} images </h1>
                  <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">{{ page.name }}</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ page.des }}</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">ViewDetails</a>
                  </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Loop variable is obj2 here. r u saying  '' obj2.images.url" ?

Comment: It was raising a 'Related object not iterable ' error. Anyway fixed it,,, had to add extraa ".all"  .Thanks :)

Comment: @ImranHossain if my answer helped you mark it please as a correct one.